# SetValue of Form

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angularfire2, angular-reactive-forms

I use angular CLI1.6, angularfire2, and firebase.
I work with an observable and I want to populate my form with values of `firebase`.

my firebase interface :

```
export class PPS
{
constructor (public Patientid : string, public traitement: string,
public datedebut = new Date, public datefin : string, 
public description: string, public effetsind, public Esresp: string, public 
medresp: string, public contactmail: string,
public contacttel: string) {}
}
```

I try this :

```
this.ppssToDisplay = this.ppssService.getSinglePPS(this.key)
.subscribe(res=>{
  this.ppsForm.controls['traitement'].setValue(this.ppssToDisplay.traitement);
  console.log(this.ppssToDisplay.traitement);
});
```

What is wrong ?  console.log(this.ppssToDisplay.traitement) send me "undefined"

Comment: What do you expect `this.ppssToDisplay.traitement` to be? `this.ppssToDisplay` is a subscription...

Comment: traitement is my date in firebase

Comment: Yes, perhaps might be that you want data from firebase, but still `this.ppssToDisplay` is a subscription because you have assigned it so ;) I think what you want is in the answers, I just wanted to point out why `this.ppssToDisplay` does not contain `traitement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.ppssToDisplay` is your observable try this,

```
this.ppssToDisplay = this.ppssService.getSinglePPS(this.key)
.subscribe(res=>{
  let response = res;
  this.ppsForm.controls['traitement'].setValue(response.traitement);
  console.log(response.traitement);
});
```

To make the value available in your html element you have to use `(ngModel)]` on the input element. For this make a global class variable say, `ppssServiceData` and load this variable in your callback like,

```
this.ppssToDisplay = this.ppssService.getSinglePPS(this.key)
 .subscribe(res=>{
   this.ppssServiceData = res;
   this.ppsForm.controls['traitement'].setValue(this.ppssServiceData.traitement);
   console.log(this.ppssServiceData.traitement);
});
```

Now, bind you date field using this variable i.e. this.ppssServiceData like

```
<input type="text" .... [(ngModel)]="ppssServiceData?.YOUR_DATE_KEY" />
```

Comment: error TS2339: Property 'traitement' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: if my value is a date i must write anything (the material Date picker doesn't get the value

Comment: i can't use the picker with your solution ?

Comment: I try this : [(ngModel)]="ppssToDisplay.datedebut | date:' d/MM/y'"

Comment: but he don't love the pipe

Comment: You have to use the pipe in `value` not in `ngModel`

Comment: value in the type script ?

Comment: it works if i don't use the picker but with picker i don't have the value

Answer (score 1):

move your property inside the subscription and assign the value to it..

```
 this.ppssService.getSinglePPS(this.key)
.subscribe(res=>{
    this.ppssToDisplay = res;
    this.ppsForm.controls['traitement'].setValue(this.ppssToDisplay.traitement);
    console.log(this.ppssToDisplay.traitement);
});
```